# Applescript do shell script can't find Android ADB

Tags: android, bash, applescript, adb

I have a couple of shell scripts stored in the */Scripts* folder of my AppleScript application.

I can access them by setting my base path

`set basePath to POSIX path of ((path to me as text)) & "Contents/Resources/Scripts/"`

But I'm only able to run the script if I call the Terminal app

```
-- This works

tell application "Terminal"
    set currentTab to do script (basePath & "install_key.sh")
end tell

-- This does not work

do shell script basePath & "install_key.sh"
```

The error on `do shell script` complains about not being able to find `adb` (Android Debug Bridge)

FWIW, here is the shell script in question (`install_key.sh`)

```
#!/bin/bash

#Find script directory
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )"

adb push $DIR"/key-dev.txt" /sdcard/ &&
adb shell mv /sdcard/key-dev.txt /sdcard/key.txt
```

Comment: So add the path to "install_key.sh" at the second line, i.e. "export PATH=${PATH}:/path/to/all/your/commands"

Comment: Wouldn't that be path to the adb? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: You need to edit the script "install_key.sh" so that it is self-contained and has the necessary paths to adb - wherever that is on your system. Either add a line starting "export PATH=" as the second line, or put the full path to adb in front of the word "adb" in your script.

Comment: The only way to know the path to adb is `which adb`
So `export PATH="which adb"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

If I understand correctly, your main issue is that your script cannot detect and hold the presence of a specific command located on a system.

**Solution**

I believe the following code will be effective in helping you achieve your goal. This applescript allows you to find whether ADB is stored on a system and store it's path in a variable. You can add the variable to your path and export as others have suggested or have a look at the export process in Apple's [TN2065](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2065/_index.html).

If ADB is not found on a system then users can receive a prompt telling them what actions to take (if that aligns with your use-case or you could begin the install sequence for ADB). To test the behavior of the script you can simply change the adp to some other (fake) command that does not exist on your system. I've added the path to the dialog so that you can see the do shell is passing the contents of the which command into a variable.

```
try

    set adbPath to do shell script "which adb"

on error errStr number errorNumber

    -- If our own error number, warn about bad data.
    if the errorNumber is not equal to 0 then
        display dialog "ADB is not loaded onto system. Please load ADB and run this app again"
        return 0 -- Return the default value (0).
    else
        -- An unknown error occurred. Resignal, so the caller
        -- can handle it, or AppleScript can display the number.
        error errStr number errorNumber
    end if

end try

if length of adbPath > 0 then display dialog "ADB found continue processing..." & adbPath
```

The structure defined in the TN2065 above is essentially:

```
$ VAR=something; export VAR $ osascript -e 'do shell script "echo $VAR"' something
```

You might also want to try the administrator option when calling the shell script:

```
do shell script "command" user name "me" password "mypassword" with administrator privileges
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, one small thing—it's `ADB` for Android Device Bridge, not `ADP`. Also, even thought I do in fact have `ADB` installed and working, your code tells me I do not.

Comment: @couzzi - Sorry about the typo and thanks for the notice. Can you try a sanity check to see if you change the which command to look for abc if it returns not found and a search of man returns found? It works as expected on my system, so just curious if a deeper problem exists on your box.

Comment: `which adb` via Terminal returns: `/Users/couzzi/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools//adb`, but the updated script above still returns the error. See [this screenshot](http://richardcouzzi.com/Screen%20Shot%202014-03-07%20at%204.40.32%20PM.png)

Comment: @couzzi - Could you click ok and then click the Replies tab on the editor? This ought to show the internal value generated from the which command. Failing that I suggest you try to use the with administrator option, which is available at the TN2065 link in the answer. You can also try any other example on that page. The idea is to verify that any do shell script command will work.

Comment: Here is the reply: `tell current application
 do shell script "which adb"
  --> error "The command exited with a non-zero status." number 1
end tell`

Comment: Worth noting this is the same error that's returned when trying with admin privileges.

Comment: What happens when you change the script to "which man"? I'd like to see if the script can locate anything at all.

Comment: That worked: `do shell script "which man" --> "/usr/bin/man"` in the reply

Comment: Can you install the adb in it's standard location? I think the problem is that your path install is not standardized so your system cannot automatically find the executable. Keep in mind that this is a problem you're likely to see on other systems depending if the user install base is correct. See this link and my suggestion about exporting the path http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/what-is-adb-and-how-to-install-it-android/.

Answer (score 0):

The [Technical Note TN2065: do shell script in AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2065/_index.html) is the key reference for this kind of issues.

> when you use just a command name instead of a complete path, the shell
>   uses a list of directories (known as your PATH) to try and find the
>   complete path to the command. For security and portability reasons, **do
>   shell script** ignores the configuration files that an interactive shell
>   would read, so you don’t get the customizations you would have in
>   Terminal.

#### First: find the full path of adb

you have to open a Terminal and issue the following command:

```
$ which adb
```

suppose the response is:

```
/Users/ronda/projects/android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

this means that the path of adb is: 
**/Users/ronda/projects/android/sdk/platform-tools**
, now we have several way to address the problem, for example follow one of these two options:

#### Option1: Fix the AppleScript

```
do shell script "PATH=${PATH}:/Users/ronda/projects/android/sdk/platform-tools; export PATH; echo $PATH; " & basePath & "install_key.sh"
```

#### Option2: Fix the shell script

for example you could specify full path to the **adb** command in your .sh this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Find script directory
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )"

/Users/ronda/projects/android/sdk/platform-tools/adb push $DIR"/key-dev.txt" /sdcard/ &&
/Users/ronda/projects/android/sdk/platform-tools/adb shell mv /sdcard/key-dev.txt /sdcard/key.txt
```

Comment: The only issue is I can't hardcode the location of the adb — this app will run on others' systems as well. Is there a way to store the result of `which adb` ?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be running the same bash configuration as your terminal application. The main difference is that Terminal uses an interactive bash and do shell script command doesn't. To run an interactive shell you can simply execute a new one with option -i (stands for interactive). When an interactive shell is opened the ~/.bashrc file is used, while non-interactive shells don't use this file.

```
do shell script "bash -i <<<" & quoted form of (basePath & "install_key.sh" as text)
```

if you don't like that you can simply execute the bashrc file or read the path variable and set it in a do shell script.